# Help with AVR and Serial ports

Tags: c, serial-port, avr, avr-gcc

I'm having problems with serial communication. I've connected an AtMega644 to a serial LCD which takes 9600 8N1. I just get garbage. By garbage I'm just getting some U,P,T and @ instead of the desired "U". I'm using the internal 8Mhz RC Osc with the fuses listed below. I suspect a timing issue but I'm not sure where I went wrong. I added a blinking LED and the timing looks right (eyeball and digital stopwatch). Any help is appreciated.

avrdude   -pm644 -cavrisp2 -Pusb -b2400 -u
         -Uflash:w:ImpactTarget.hex:a
         -Ulfuse:w:0xe2:m
         -Uhfuse:w:0xd8:m
         -Uefuse:w:0xff:m

```
#define F_CPU 8000000
#define BAUDRATE 9600
#define UBRRVAL (F_CPU/(BAUDRATE*16UL)) -1


#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdio.h>



/***************************************************** USART_Init()
*
*
**/
void USART_Init () {
    //Set baud rate
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(UBRRVAL>>8);   //high byte
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char) UBRRVAL;       //low byte

    //Asynchronous normal speed
    UCSR0A = (0<<U2X0);

    //Enable Transmitter and Receiver and Interrupt on receive complete
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<TXEN0) | (1<<RXCIE0);

    //page 186 Set asynchronous mode,no parity, 1 stop bit, 8 bit size
    UCSR0C= (0<<UMSEL00)| (0<<UMSEL01)|             //Async
            (0<<UPM00)  | (0<<UPM01)  |             //Parity None
            (0<<USBS0)  |                           //Stop bits 1
            (0<<UCSZ02) | (1<<UCSZ01) |(1<<UCSZ00); //8 Bits

    //enable interrupts
    sei();
}


/******************************************** send_btye
* sends one byte to serial port
**/
void send_byte (char data) {
    while ( ! (UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) )
        /* NOOP */;
    UDR0 = data;
}


/**
 * _delay_ms has a short time so this is an extension
 */
void delay_ms (int time) {
    for (int i = 0; i < time; i++) {
        _delay_ms(1);
    }
}

/****************************** main *********/
int main () {
    USART_Init();
    DDRA = 0xff;

    for (;;) {
        send_byte('U');
        delay_ms(500);
        PORTA ^=_BV(PA0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this configuration ever worked before? Is this your first time trying to activate UART with that MCU?

Comment: Here is a cheap logic analyzer (130 EUR) http://www.saleae.com/logic. It's always useful to have. Maybe it fits in your budget.

Comment: @Dor, this would be the first time. It looks like there is a timing error and I can't figure out where

Comment: What is the catalog number of the LCD? How's the LCD is configured to communicate? Maybe it needs a parity bit or no stop bit etc.

Comment: Check if the MCU UART peripheral has an error field, indicating the status of communication/transfer.

Comment: @whoplisp Cool tool. Do you know if it will run on a windows VM on a Mac?

Comment: @Jim they have software for Mac. You can try it. Without real hardware it simulates some pulses. I only used it in Linux and Windows, though.

Comment: The logic analyzer above is very small but slow. Next I will buy one of those: http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/794668827/aliencortex-av for 150USD or http://dangerousprototypes.com/2010/02/25/prototype-open-logic-sniffer-logic-analyzer-2/ (assembled) for **50USD**. They are both based on FPGA.

Comment: Since you aren't at the point where you're trying to receive, don't enable interrupts and see if that helps anything (though I'd expect outright silence from the port if that were the problem).  Also, can you connect the port to PC terminal program to see if it receives the same garbage?

Comment: I'll have more detail tomorrow. When I know exactly what the internal Osc is running at maybe I can tune it with OSCCAL. I would be nice to get it to 8Mhz +-2% or maybe the 7.37Mhz to work with all baud rates.

Comment: I hooked up a logic analyzer and it seems my internal RC OSC is dropping off from time to time and is not running at the right rates. thus the garbage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you're right - it's probably a timing issue: the internal RC oscillator is usually much too imprecise to use for USART.

I would try to attach an external crystal (and set the fuses correspondingly) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your `UBRRVAL` doesn't fully parenthesize its expression so when it is expanded in a context like `UBRRVAL >> 8` the `>> 8` does not apply the way you expect.

Answer (score -1):

this is exactly what took 3 days of my project time, just try to set Baudrate at (9600) and set the (X2) option for Baudrate. it should work.